# EasyNetQ Wait for event from ISubscriptionResult

Tags: c#, f#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I am using EasyNetQ for mamanging my RabbitMq messenging bus using f# well its quite simple this one publishes messenges:

```
let HandleBusResponse (data:BaseFrame) (bus:IBus) : ISubscriptionResult = 
    let handler = Action<RequestMessage>(fun request ->
        let cabinetSubscribeId = sprintf "Project.%i" request.ProjectId
            match request.FrameType with 
                  | FrameType.UNDEFINED -> 
                    let response = ResponseService.BusRequestFactory request data
                  | _ -> 
                    let response = ResponseService.BusRequestFactory request data 
    bus.Publish<ResponseMessage>(response, cabinetSubscribeId))
```

And this method(subscriber) is called somewhere in application like:

```
HandleBusResponse data bus
//WAIT FOR MESSAGE ARRIVAL
informationPools.AddToConnectionPool(data.ProjectId, client) |> ignore 
ClientInfoHandler client data |> Async.RunSynchronously|> ignore
```

Basically the same way it works in c#.

Now this code is out of subscriber handler, my question is is it possible to detect from this part

> //WAIT FOR MESSAGE ARRIVAL

using some sort of while if anything new arrived (remembering that second code snippet is outside subscribe handler)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could post a complete minimal example that compiled and worked in F# Interactive, it would be easier to directly implement the solution for your problem.  However, one solution that should work in general would be awaiting events.  In F#, you can create events like this:

```ml
let requestArrived = Event<RequestMessage>()
let responsePublished = Event<ResponseMessage>()
```

Then, you can asynchronously await those events and handle the data that they produce:

```ml
let rec messageLoop<'message> f (event: IEvent<'message>) = 
    async {
        let! message = event |> Async.AwaitEvent 
        message |> f
        return! messageLoop f event
    }
```

So, in your `// WAIT FOR MESSAGE ARRIVAL` block, you could do something like this (depending on whether you want to handle requests or responses, or what you want to do with them:

```ml
requestArrived.Publish |> messageLoop (fun request -> printfn "Received Request: %A" request)
// AND/OR
responsePublished.Publish |> messageLoop (fun response -> printfn "Sent Response: %A" response)
```

Then, you can update your handler to trigger the events as requried:

```ml
    let handler = Action<RequestMessage>(fun request ->        
        requestArrived.Trigger(request)
        let cabinetSubscribeId = sprintf "Project.%i" request.ProjectId
        let response = 
            match request.FrameType with 
            | FrameType.UNDEFINED -> 
                ResponseService.BusRequestFactory request data
            | _ -> 
                ResponseService.BusRequestFactory request data 
        bus.Publish<ResponseMessage>(response, cabinetSubscribeId)
        responsePublished.Trigger(response))
```